# Populate the longitude and latitude using google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have the following html and javascript. The javascript populates location details from the google maps api to the html form fields. The idea is someone to enter their original location which is populated in the first html form fields and then enter a second location that is populated in the second form. This works perfectly.

Now I also want to populate the form with the longitude and latitude of the first and second locations.

```
*<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Start typing your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="addressone">
  <input type="text" id="street_number" name="street_number" />
  <input type="text" id="route" name="street_name" />
  <input type="text" id="locality" name="town_city" />
  <input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" />
  <input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postcode" />
  <input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
  <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" />
  <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" />

</div>
<div id="locationField2">
  <input id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Start typing your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="addresstwo">
  <input type="text" id="street_number2" name="street_number2" />
  <input type="text" id="route2" name="street_name2" />
  <input type="text" id="locality2" name="town_city2" />
  <input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_12" name="administrative_area_level_12" />
  <input type="text" id="postal_code2" name="postcode2" />
  <input type="text" id="country2" name="country2" />
  <input type="text" id="longitude2" name="longitude2" />
  <input type="text" id="latitude2" name="latitude2" />
</div>

    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress(autocomplete, "");
  });

  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress(autocomplete2, "2");
  });

}

function fillInAddress(autocomplete, unique) {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    if (!!document.getElementById(component + unique)) {
      document.getElementById(component + unique).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component + unique).disabled = false;
    }
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType] && document.getElementById(addressType + unique)) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType + unique).value = val;
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAqYwW9d0lnFABF-0NKCTrO__G_d3d958k&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>*
```

The code populates all the required fields but does not populate the longitude and latitude. Any work around?

Comment: Where is the code that you expect to populate the latitude and longitude?

Comment: @geocode everything is in the shared code. Look at the html part

Comment: There is no code to populate the latitude and longitude...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any code to populate the latitude and longitude fields.  Add this to `fillInAddress`:

```
document.getElementById('latitude'+unique).value = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('longitude'+unique).value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

complete function:

```
function fillInAddress(autocomplete, unique) {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    if (!!document.getElementById(component + unique)) {
      document.getElementById(component + unique).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component + unique).disabled = false;
    }
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType] && document.getElementById(addressType + unique)) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType + unique).value = val;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('latitude'+unique).value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById('longitude'+unique).value = place.geometry.location.lng();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nqxphnzo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress(autocomplete, "");
  });

  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress(autocomplete2, "2");
  });

}

function fillInAddress(autocomplete, unique) {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    if (!!document.getElementById(component + unique)) {
      document.getElementById(component + unique).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component + unique).disabled = false;
    }
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType] && document.getElementById(addressType + unique)) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType + unique).value = val;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('latitude' + unique).value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById('longitude' + unique).value = place.geometry.location.lng();

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);

function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Start typing your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="addressone">
  <input type="text" id="street_number" name="street_number" />
  <input type="text" id="route" name="street_name" />
  <input type="text" id="locality" name="town_city" />
  <input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" />
  <input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postcode" />
  <input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
  <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" />
  <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" />

</div>
<div id="locationField2">
  <input id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Start typing your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="addresstwo">
  <input type="text" id="street_number2" name="street_number2" />
  <input type="text" id="route2" name="street_name2" />
  <input type="text" id="locality2" name="town_city2" />
  <input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_12" name="administrative_area_level_12" />
  <input type="text" id="postal_code2" name="postcode2" />
  <input type="text" id="country2" name="country2" />
  <input type="text" id="longitude2" name="longitude2" />
  <input type="text" id="latitude2" name="latitude2" />
</div>
```