# Using this google maps API auto-complete example. Can this function be modified get the longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I need to use this autocomplete form to get the users location if the GPS is unavailable. However, this function is only set up to find address components. I also need the longitude and latitude from geometry.

The plan is to save there longitude and latitude to storage and then ajax it to get some php results.

I believe the function fillInAddress() is where I need to add something.

Any help is appreciated!

[There is a JSFIDDLE on this google Page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)
(scroll down after clicking, there is a link to a fiddle so I don't have to show you my key)

[MY TEST PAGE](https://www.aarontomlinson.com/indextest.php)
(click decline)

[MY CURRENT PAGE](https://www.aarontomlinson.com/index.php)
(click allow)

GOOGLE MAPS API AUTO COMPLETE EXAMPLE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
             You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
             https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
        -->
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate the longitude and latitude using google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334324/populate-the-longitude-and-latitude-using-google-maps-api)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Google Maps - Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845516/javascript-google-maps-autofill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here.

[Lat and Long auto complete](http://jsfiddle.net/0b0az4fr/)

```
 function initialize() {
        var address = (document.getElementById('my-address'));
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);
        autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
        }
      });
}
function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("my-address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      alert("Latitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      alert("Longitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } 

      else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```